# Не открывается камера для создания изображения

Tags: android

При нажатии на `ImageView` открывается диалоговое окно с выбором способа добавления изображения в `ImageView` (из галереи или с камеры). Пытаюсь реализовать добавление через камеру, но почему-то если нажимаю "Сделать снимок" не открывается камера. Что не так?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView img1;

    static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 2;

    static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA = 2;

    String dirName = "MyImage";
    File currentImageFileForStep = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img1 = findViewById(R.id.img1);

        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showImageSelectionDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void selectImageFromCamera() {

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                &&(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                &&(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            currentImageFileForStep = createImageFileFromCamera();

            if (currentImageFileForStep != null) {
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "ru.test.testimage.fileprovider",
                        currentImageFileForStep);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    },
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        }

    }

    private void showImageSelectionDialog() {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Выбор")
                .setItems(R.array.attachment_variants, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (which == 0) {
                            //electImageFromGallery();
                        } else if (which == 1) {
                            selectImageFromCamera();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .create();

        if (!isFinishing()) {
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    private void createImageFolder() {
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + dirName);

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + dirName);
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private String createImageFileName() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String fileName = "img_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        return fileName;
    }

    @Nullable
    private File createImageFileFromCamera() {

        String filename = createImageFileName();

        createImageFolder();

        File image = new File(dirName, filename);
        try {
            if (image.createNewFile()) {
                return image;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    selectImageFromCamera();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Нет прав на работу с камерой", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (img1 != null) {

            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            switch(requestCode) {
                case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentImageFileForStep.getAbsolutePath());
                        img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        img1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                        img1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

В Манифесте добавлены разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы запрашиваете только права на камеру, а нужно ещё на доступ к хранилищу.

Попробуйте так:

```
if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
&&(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
&&(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
{
    ....
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        },
        REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
}
```

Comment: Переделала, не помогло. Дело не в этом, там что-то другое не то я делаю кажется

Answer (score 0):

У вас открытие камеры происходит по условию: `if (currentImageFileForStep != null)`

`currentImageFileForStep` определяете методом (строка выше):

```
currentImageFileForStep = createImageFileFromCamera();
```

который скорее всего возвращает `NULL`

Переходим в метод, и видим строку: `File image = new File(dirName, filename);` В `dirName` это относительный путь, а не полный, в результате чего в `try` создание файла не происходит, и метод возвращает `NULL`.
p.s. Такие ошибки легко отлавливаются в logcat - рекомендую заглядывать туда в процессе разработки.

Comment: Уже сделала спасибо.